# Laravel @yield Show URL first

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, yield

I am having a problem showing the http path before an image in my meta tags.

In my Blog Post Blade I have this:      `@section('photo', $blog->photo)`

In my Front View Blade I have this:
`<meta property="og:image" content="@yield('photo')">`

It successfully shows the image filename as expected..  But I tried several ways to include the URL path before it..  `{{ asset('assets/images/blogs/' . $blog->photo) }}`

How would I accomplish this?  Thanks

Comment: do you want to show the whole url?

Comment: your point is not clear. please show us the code

Comment: Sorry- A added the code now. My bad

Comment: do you want to show the whole url?  -->  yes..  $blog->photo only shows the filename but I need the whole URL

Comment: I am pretty sure you miss a `@endsection`

Comment: i posted the answer and i got it in this way if i am not wrong

Answer (score 1):

you can use image path in the header meta tag as below:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ asset('assets/images/blogs/'.$blog->photo) }}" />
```

Comment: That's how it was originally, but it would constantly pull the wrong image..  It would link to an image on a whole different post